# Laravel nested whereIn from multiple tables

Tags: laravel, subquery

I'm using Laravel 5.7. How do i rewrite below code as a single nested query?

I'm currently fetching the result using 2 database queries. I go through some of the answers in stackoverflow, but i still have doubts in nesting multiple tables

```
  $connectedParts = DB::table('part_connections as c')
          ->join('parts_master as p', 'p.id', '=', 'c.part_number_id')
          ->where('c.part_number_id', $partId)
          ->where('p.id', $partId)
          ->pluck('connected_to');

  $connectedComponents = DB::table('part_connections as pc')
                            ->join('parts_master as pm', 'pm.id', '=', 'pc.connected_to')
                            ->where('part_number_id',$partId)
                            ->where('pm.part_type','1')
                            ->whereIn('connected_to', $connectedParts)
                            ->pluck('connected_to');
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the advantage of your solution?

Comment: I just wanted to know how to nest this query, may be it'll be of some help in the future

Answer (score 0):

Set your relationship properly in your model first then try this query:

```
//PartConnection model - add for eager loading
public function master() {
    return $this->belongsTo('PartMaster::class', 'connected_to', 'id');
}

$query = PartConnection::whereHas(‘master’, function($qry)) use ($partId) {
    $qry->where(‘parts_master.id’, $partId);
    $qry->where(‘parts_master.part_type’, 1);
});

$query->where(‘part_number_id’, $partId);

$connectedComponents = $query->get();
```

## update

Try this then:

```
$connectedComponents = DB::table('part_connections as pc')
                        ->join('parts_master as pm', function($join) {
                            $join->on('pc.connected_to', '=', 'pm.id');
                            $join->on('pc.part_number_id', '=', 'pm.id');
                        }) //updated this - removed ;
                        ->where('part_number_id',$partId)
                        ->where('pm.part_type','1')
                        ->get();
```

Comment: table 'part_connection' is really a big table, so i didn't create columns 'created_at' and 'updated_at'. I want to use Query builder instead

Comment: sorry got it wrong, try it again, look at the comment

Comment: Note: Really weird, based from what you mentioned, the only issue you had was you were joining the table 2x, so we combine the 2 join query into 1. check the join condition if it is correct.

Comment: Actually i was not fetching a result which satisfies both 'pc.connected_to', '=', 'pm.id'  AND ('pc.part_number_id', '=', 'pm.id' at a time.

Comment: so you want to fetch them separately? If yes, then maybe rather just join, subquery will be required for that

Comment: how? Just like i did?